# Using `gopy`, how to properly pass []string from Python to Go?

Tags: python, go

My Go code is:

```
func Test(websites []string) {
    fmt.Print("test")
}
```

I use `gopy build` to produce the `httpget.so` file

I then try to load ans use this module, `httpget.so`, in my Python code:

```
import httpget
print dir(httpget)

httpget.Test(["aaaa"])
```

But calling that function results in a panic on the Go side:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x1 pc=0x103998688]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main.cgo_func_httpget_Test(0x1)
    /private/var/folders/yg/tx1wr1c5233fd299lpqnvjy40000gn/T/gopy-066392802/httpget.go:173 +0x18

goroutine 18 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1
```

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Your function accepts a `string` not a `[]string`

Comment: sorry, the code is ```func Test(websites []string) {
 fmt.Print(websites)
}```

Comment: Does your Go code work if you use just `fmt.Println("test")` in the body of `Test()`?

Comment: @kostix no, it too many arguments in call to Test

Comment: Uh, what? I mean, replace `fmt.Print(websites)` with `fmt.Println("test")` but keep the rest of the code on both side the same. I did not tell you to not pass your data to `Test()`, just to ignore it inside that function to know whether it fails accessing the argument data or earlier.

Comment: @kostix ok,i know.i use your method, go use `Test("aaa")`,it `cannot use "aaa" (type string) as type []string in argument to Test`, i dont't know how to send a []string use python,python import httptest,it still error:`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x1 pc=0x102434698]`

Comment: Are you kidding? I mean use `func Test(websites []string) { fmt.Println("test"); }` to see if panicking happens upon accessing `websites` or not. Was it really this much undecipherable in my two attempts?

Comment: @kostix i already use your code `func Test(websites []string) { fmt.Println("test"); }`  the same error.

Answer (score 0):

ok,i find the way!! 23333

golang

```
var (
    WebSites = [1]string{"aaa"}
)
```

in the python

```
import httpget
s = httpget.GetWebSites()
s[0] = "http://www.baidu.com"
httpget.Test(s)
```